# What is wrong with these suggested edits and why are they rejected?

Tags: discussion

I'm reviewing my recent suggested edits and don't understand why these five are rejected because:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are **unnecessary or** make the post **more confusing**

- https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17526
- https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17532
- https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17437
- https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17435
- https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17434

None of the above examples contained a question in the title, and without reading anything else, one could not tell what the questioner would possibly try to ask or achieve. Each suggested edit clarifies the question's primary purpose a lot, making it *an improvement* and certainly not *more confusing*, for readers simply scrolling through the homepage and looking at the titles.

What can be improved to avoid future useless edits, which is a waste of time?

Answer (score 3):

#### Image sizes

One thing that I have noticed is that you change the URL of an image (taking this [suggested edit](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17538) as an example), from:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVE.jpg
```

to

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVEm.jpg
```

However, if you do that, then, *when you click on the image*, to view the high resolution image, you are presented with an inferior lower-res image. Try clicking this image below:

[image: This is a low res image]

Now, if you click this image, you will get a superior image and better detail (which is always useful):

[image: This is a hi res image]

Also, the top image *seems* a bit too small in the overall scheme of the post, IMHO.

However, if you like that "smallness" but still want to be able to click to a higher resolution image then you'd have to reference *two image URLs*, one for each size, something like this:

```
[![Extruder][1]][2]

...

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVEm.jpg "Extruder"
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVE.jpg
```

This seems a bit too convoluted for my liking though, and might get messed up when other URLs (links and images) are added by the editor - not sure, not tested it. It would be good if it did get handled correctly though.

---

#### Adding image hover tags

One other thing, after the image URL, if you repeat the image description in quotes, like this:

```
[![This is a hi res image][3]][3]

...

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVE.jpg "This is a hi res image"
```

when you hover the mouse cursor over the image, the usually invisible (and seemingly pointless) image description now shows up in a "hover tag/label". Try it with the two images above.

This gives new rhyme and reason for adding *meaningful* description image descriptions, i.e.

```
[![Extruder][1]][1]

[![Knurled drive gear][2]][2]

...

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVE.jpg "Extruder"
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFo8A.png "Knurled drive gear"
```

rather than

```
[![photo 1 of hotend][1]][1]

[![photo 2 of hotend][2]][2]

...

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOVEm.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFo8Am.png
```

especially as neither of the photos are of a hotend, per se.
:-)

The editing in of "image hover tags" *is* mentioned in [Useful things to check for when cleaning up posts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/500/4762) but not (as I have just realised) actually *explained*..! I'll add the examples above to that post somewhere, so thanks for bringing that to fore.

---

#### Spaces and SI units

Also, please see [Don't forget the space!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/297/4762). The space between "1.75" and "mm" should not be removed. However, it *should* (or *could*) be replaced with a `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write-up.

Comment: Thats OK, I needed to make an example of implementing image hover tags anyway. I am hopefully just trying to clear any issues up that you might have. As I've said before, thanks for helping out around the site. I do very little "site activity" now, just mod stuff and review queues. Rarely have time to actually answer questions these days unfortunately. The same goes for some other members too, I think - job changes, less free time, etc.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the other reviewers of your suggested edits, but...

Possibly, at first glance at your links, I would avoid just changing the title into a question (from an already grammatically correct statement) on an *old established* question - as this adds little to the post and just bumps the question (again).

From your examples: #1, #2, #4 and #5 just seem to change a couple of words, but with little (or no) added value - apart from making a grammatical question, which isn't really strictly necessary. Many sites use title statements rather than questions - to be honest, either seem acceptable, so just changing titles (of old questions) into grammatically correct interrogations seems unnecessary. You could do that for the new posts, as they aren't yet established - but if you are trying to look up an older question and the title has been changed, then that could be taken as "making the post more confusing".

Also, there are *a lot* of question titles that aren't questions (but statements instead), and converting them *all* would mean a lot of suggested edit reviews - all for little to no gain.

Focusing on #5 for a moment, adding the "Longer LK5 Pro" to the title is *redundant* as the question is already tagged with [longer-lk5](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longer-lk5). Generally, when a question is tagged with "*something*", that "*something*" is then *removed* from the title due to redundancy (see the section **Avoid putting tags in the question title** under [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/4424636) to [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/4424636)).

That said, your example #3 does seem useful as it does (admittedly) describe the issue better. That was one that I rejected, purely because (IIRC) it is an old question that already has an answer (that probably should have been accepted, had the user returned to the site after posting the question).

Actually, sticking with #3, the "*with TMC2208 and Klipper*" in the title should be removed as it is redundant, due to the tags (going by what was said above), which (by those rules) would leave the title as just:

> Creality Sprite Extruder custom install on Ender 3 Pro

which *really* is *utterly meaningless*! LOL. :-) So, maybe the *part* of your suggested edit that includes the voltage is a very good idea - even though the answer then states that the voltages should be ignored - so something like this:

> How to configure the TMC2208 Driver Voltage for a Creality Sprite Extruder custom install

and maybe tag with [ender-3-pro](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-3-pro), if there is one, otherwise the existing [ender-3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-3) tag might suffice..? However, I'm not sure how the Ender printers are meant to be tagged, and I might be wrong. There was a Meta post/discussion somewhere by Trish and/or 0scar about a possible hierarchy of tags, i.e. something *like* [creality](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creality) and[ender](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender) and then [3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3), which I think was rejected - however, I've had a good look and really can't find the meta post.

So, in summary, I would reject all of those edits again, apart from #3 as the title is a bit of a mess anyway - remove the redundant already tagged info from the title and mention the stepper driver voltages. If you suggest that edit, I'll accept it :-)

#### Suggestions

As this is a small site (with little traffic, as discussed in your [previous meta post](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/582/4762)), most of the questions have been edited to death already and as such, it can be difficult to find things to fix. It is probably best to stick to **new posts** that haven't yet been edited, or if an older post is blatantly incorrect and has been missed then that should be fixed.

You might find this useful: [Useful things to check for when cleaning up posts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/500/4762)

I notice that you've added some tags in other suggested edits. Many of these tags have no description, which can make it a bit harder to review the suggested edit, w.r.t the validity of the tag.  If you could edit such "empty" tags, with descriptions and usage, that would be *really* useful. In which case, these are related:

- [Do we have a template for a tag excerpt?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/565/4762)
- [Circular tag wiki excerpts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/116/4762)

---

##### The problem with mods doing reviews

As there really are *so few* regular users on the site, the review queues often fall to the moderators - otherwise they would never be cleared.

One issue with mods undertaking reviews, is that we are *unable* to vote as normal users, see [Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/280335). That means that only one vote of ours is needed, which *seems* very undemocratic. I'm not happy about this, and would much prefer to have a community of votes, as is the usual case.

Unfortunately, we don't have that luxury, and so some votes may seem autocratic in nature. However, as you have done, bringing up any perceived slight is always a good idea, and raising them here in Meta is always good for a discussion.

Comment: Can you still re-approve #3?

Comment: There is nothing in that review queue currently, so I can't review it again, as there is nothing to review. Previously reviewed posts can not be re-reviewed, there is no such option, even for mods, unfortunately.

Comment: I've resubmitted the edit.